# Eager Loading Gets Incomplete Results

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm converting a legacy .NET Framework solution to .NET Core 2.1. We're used to the built-in under-the-hood explicit loading of navigation properties EF 6 performed, but we don't want to go to the effort of writing out the explicit loading in the code everywhere now if we can avoid it. We also make extensive repeated use of navigation properties and don't want to take the performance hit lazy loading implies whenever we revisit a navigation property. It seems like eager loading is the solution we want; however, eager loading is only getting us back a small subset of the navigation property rows we want.

I've tried using explicit loading to confirm that there's no problem with my LINQ filter. Explicit loading retrieves the complete set of expected rows

Assuming tables Things and OtherThings, and cross-table ThingsOtherThings, the cross table is set up in OnModelCreating like this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ThingsOtherThings>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK__ThingsO__A2B5777C716F82C1");
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("(newid())");
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Thing).WithMany(p => p.ThingsOtherThings).HasForeignKey(d => d.ThingId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull).HasConstraintName("FK_ThingsOtherThing_Thing");
                entity.HasOne(d => d.OtherThing).WithMany(p => p.ThingsOtherThings).HasForeignKey(d => d.OtherThingId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull).HasConstraintName("FK_ThingsOtherThing_OtherThing");
            });
```

The eager-loading version looks like this:

```cs
var things = context.Things.Where(_ => ids.ContainsKey(_.Id)).Include(_ => _.ThingsOtherThings).ToList();
```

This retrieves two Thing records, with about 6 ThingsOtherThings between them on the navigation property, which is incorrect. If I use the following code instead:

```cs
var things = context.Things.Where(_ => ids.ContainsKey(_.Id);
foreach (var thing in things)
  context.Entry(thing).Collection(_ => _.ThingsOtherThings).Load();
```

then I end up with the same Thing records, but they have about 70 ThingsOtherThings between them on the navigation property, which is what I want.

Why is eager loading getting different results? How can I use eager loading and get the same in-memory results I'm getting from explicit loading?

Comment: What does the data in the database actually look like? I would look at the data in all 3 tables and see if you are getting what you expect.

Comment: The data in the database looks like the data I get back when I use explicit loading. The data I get back when I use eager loading is a subset of that data.

Comment: can you profile the database and look at the SQL that is getting generated to see if that provides any insight?

Comment: Really frustrating, but it's the same SQL getting generated in both cases: SELECT [t1].[Id]
FROM [Things] AS [t1]

SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Name], [t].[Etc]
FROM [Things] AS [t]
ORDER BY [t].[Id]

SELECT [t.ThingsOtherThings].[Id], [t.ThingsOtherThings].[Value], [t.ThingsOtherThings].[OtherThingId], [t.ThingsOtherThings].[ThingId]
FROM [ThingsOtherThings] AS [t.ThingsOtherThings]